# Return all columns if a row in that column contains a specific string

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to come up with a way to return all of the "invoice items" in a column if any of them contain "Warranty Credit" as an "Invoice Item Description". I've posted an image below to try and make it make more sense. As you can see below the second invoice is displaying even though "Warranty Credit" is not listed.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

```
WHERE EXISTS 
    (SELECT ARII.Description
        FROM 
            AR_Customer ARC
            Inner JOIN AR_Customer_Site         ARCS    On ARC.Customer_Id = ARCS.Customer_Id AND ARCS.Customer_Id = ARC.Customer_Id
            INNER JOIN AR_Customer_System       ARCSYS  On ARCS.Customer_Site_Id = ARCSYS.Customer_Site_Id
            INNER JOIN AR_Branch                ARB     ON ARB.Branch_Id = ARC.Branch_Id
            INNER JOIN AR_Invoice               ARIN    ON ARIN.Customer_Site_Id = ARCS.Customer_Site_Id
            INNER JOIN AR_Invoice_Item          ARII    ON ARII.Invoice_Id = ARIN.Invoice_Id                
        WHERE ARII.[Description] LIKE ('Warranty Credit') OR ARII.[Description] = ('Warranty Credit T'))
    AND ARIN.Invoice_Date > dateadd(MONTH, -1, getdate()) 
ORDER BY ARIN.Invoice_Number
```

Comment: In your `LIKE` statement, you would probably want to use the wildcard `%`. `WHERE ARII.[Description] LIKE '%Warranty Credit%'`

Comment: `WHERE ARII.[Description] LIKE ('Warranty Credit')` should be `WHERE ARII.[Description] LIKE ('%Warranty Credit%')` or perhaps if you don't want like conditions `WHERE ARII.[Description] =('Warranty Credit')`

Comment: Those are very specific results that I am looking for.  Either way it doesn't solve the issue that I am having.  Thanks though!

Comment: This "code dump" can not possibly be the smallest code that shows the problem. Please edit it so it is.

Comment: Last time I posted for SQL I was told to add all that I had.  Thought I'd save time.  Edited...

Comment: I think your entire query is needed, but @Bohemian wasn't talking about that... he was just saying simplify the query with some test data... all of the joins and lengthy query isn't really needed to reproduce the problem. Regardless, i understood your question and it was merely a correlation issue as i described below.

Comment: Ah I see.  Thanks for the explanation and I'll be sure to do that next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing what exists returns. Use IN for this use case:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ARC.Customer_Number As 'Customer Number',
    ARC.Customer_Name AS 'Customer Name',
    ARB.Branch_Code AS 'Site Branch',
    ARCS.Site_Number As 'Site Number',
    ARCS.Business_Name AS 'Site Name',
    ARII.Quantity AS 'Invoice Item Quantity',
    ARII.Rate AS 'Invoice Item Rate',
    ARII.Amount AS 'Invoice Item Amount',
    ARII.Description AS 'Invoice Item Description',
    SYSY.System_Code AS 'System Code',
    ARIN.Invoice_Number AS 'Invoice Number',
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ARIN.Invoice_Date, 10) AS 'Invoice Date',
    ARCAT.Category_Code AS 'Category',
    ARIN.Memo AS 'Resolution Notes'

FROM 
    AR_Customer ARC
    Inner JOIN AR_Customer_Site         ARCS    On ARC.Customer_Id = ARCS.Customer_Id AND ARCS.Customer_Id = ARC.Customer_Id
    INNER JOIN AR_Customer_System       ARCSYS  On ARCS.Customer_Site_Id = ARCSYS.Customer_Site_Id
    INNER JOIN AR_Branch                ARB     ON ARB.Branch_Id = ARC.Branch_Id
    INNER JOIN AR_Invoice               ARIN    ON ARIN.Customer_Site_Id = ARCS.Customer_Site_Id
    INNER JOIN AR_Invoice_Item          ARII    ON ARII.Invoice_Id = ARIN.Invoice_Id
    Inner JOIN SY_System                SYSY    On ARCSYS.System_Id = SYSY.System_Id
    INNER JOIN SV_Service_Ticket        SVVT    ON ARCSYS.Customer_System_Id = SVVT.Customer_System_Id AND ARII.Service_Ticket_Id = SVVT.Service_Ticket_Id
    INNER JOIN AR_Customer_Recurring    ARCR    On ARCSYS.Customer_System_Id = ARCR.Customer_System_Id
    INNER JOIN AR_Item                  ARI     On ARCR.Item_Id = ARI.Item_Id
    Inner JOIN SS_Item_Type             SSIT    On ARI.Item_Type_Id = SSIT.Item_Type_Id
    INNER JOIN AR_Category              ARCAT   ON ARCAT.Category_Id = ARI.Category_Id

WHERE ARIN.Invoice_Number in
    (SELECT ARIN.Invoice_Number
        FROM 
            AR_Customer ARC
            Inner JOIN AR_Customer_Site         ARCS    On ARC.Customer_Id = ARCS.Customer_Id AND ARCS.Customer_Id = ARC.Customer_Id
            INNER JOIN AR_Customer_System       ARCSYS  On ARCS.Customer_Site_Id = ARCSYS.Customer_Site_Id
            INNER JOIN AR_Branch                ARB     ON ARB.Branch_Id = ARC.Branch_Id
            INNER JOIN AR_Invoice               ARIN    ON ARIN.Customer_Site_Id = ARCS.Customer_Site_Id
            INNER JOIN AR_Invoice_Item          ARII    ON ARII.Invoice_Id = ARIN.Invoice_Id                
        WHERE ARII.[Description] like ('%Warranty Credit%') OR ARII.[Description] = ('Warranty Credit T'))
    AND ARIN.Invoice_Date > dateadd(MONTH, -1, getdate()) 
ORDER BY ARIN.Invoice_Number
```

Alternatively, you could exists if you correlate that clause with a predicate from the outer query... i.e. add a where clause to check the outer and inner query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ARC.Customer_Number As 'Customer Number',
    ARC.Customer_Name AS 'Customer Name',
    ARB.Branch_Code AS 'Site Branch',
    ARCS.Site_Number As 'Site Number',
    ARCS.Business_Name AS 'Site Name',
    ARII.Quantity AS 'Invoice Item Quantity',
    ARII.Rate AS 'Invoice Item Rate',
    ARII.Amount AS 'Invoice Item Amount',
    ARII.Description AS 'Invoice Item Description',
    SYSY.System_Code AS 'System Code',
    ARIN.Invoice_Number AS 'Invoice Number',
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ARIN.Invoice_Date, 10) AS 'Invoice Date',
    ARCAT.Category_Code AS 'Category',
    ARIN.Memo AS 'Resolution Notes'

FROM 
    AR_Customer ARC
    Inner JOIN AR_Customer_Site         ARCS    On ARC.Customer_Id = ARCS.Customer_Id AND ARCS.Customer_Id = ARC.Customer_Id
    INNER JOIN AR_Customer_System       ARCSYS  On ARCS.Customer_Site_Id = ARCSYS.Customer_Site_Id
    INNER JOIN AR_Branch                ARB     ON ARB.Branch_Id = ARC.Branch_Id
    INNER JOIN AR_Invoice               ARIN    ON ARIN.Customer_Site_Id = ARCS.Customer_Site_Id
    INNER JOIN AR_Invoice_Item          ARII    ON ARII.Invoice_Id = ARIN.Invoice_Id
    Inner JOIN SY_System                SYSY    On ARCSYS.System_Id = SYSY.System_Id
    INNER JOIN SV_Service_Ticket        SVVT    ON ARCSYS.Customer_System_Id = SVVT.Customer_System_Id AND ARII.Service_Ticket_Id = SVVT.Service_Ticket_Id
    INNER JOIN AR_Customer_Recurring    ARCR    On ARCSYS.Customer_System_Id = ARCR.Customer_System_Id
    INNER JOIN AR_Item                  ARI     On ARCR.Item_Id = ARI.Item_Id
    Inner JOIN SS_Item_Type             SSIT    On ARI.Item_Type_Id = SSIT.Item_Type_Id
    INNER JOIN AR_Category              ARCAT   ON ARCAT.Category_Id = ARI.Category_Id

WHERE ARIN.Invoice_Number in
    (SELECT ARIN2.Invoice_Number
        FROM 
            AR_Customer ARC
            Inner JOIN AR_Customer_Site         ARCS    On ARC.Customer_Id = ARCS.Customer_Id AND ARCS.Customer_Id = ARC.Customer_Id
            INNER JOIN AR_Customer_System       ARCSYS  On ARCS.Customer_Site_Id = ARCSYS.Customer_Site_Id
            INNER JOIN AR_Branch                ARB     ON ARB.Branch_Id = ARC.Branch_Id
            INNER JOIN AR_Invoice               ARIN2    ON ARIN2.Customer_Site_Id = ARCS.Customer_Site_Id
            INNER JOIN AR_Invoice_Item          ARII    ON ARII.Invoice_Id = ARIN.Invoice_Id                
        WHERE 
            (ARII.[Description] like ('%Warranty Credit%') OR ARII.[Description] = ('Warranty Credit T'))
            and ARIN2.Invoice_Number = ARIN.Invoice_Number) --notice this part
    AND ARIN.Invoice_Date > dateadd(MONTH, -1, getdate()) 
ORDER BY ARIN.Invoice_Number
```

Comment: That was exactly the issue.  Thanks for the help!  Worked exactly like I'd hoped.

Comment: No problem at all @snapper. Good luck mate.